# Django: I can´t delete users in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

So I have a the get_user_model for my users, but when I try to delete one of them this appear

```
OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/6/delete/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: provide your code

Comment: Normally that means you did not run migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Anything associated with the database is due to migrations in Django. Run this in your CLI:

```
py manage.py migrate
```